# How to show Material shadow on appbar in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm making a custom backdrop effect and want to show `appBar` below the custom `Material` `body` of `Scaffold`. Screenshot below shows how `appbar` is clipping the `shadow` drawn by the `Material` widget.

[image]

**Expected result:** Shadow of `Material` should be properly visible on top of `appBar`.

Below is sample code:
`body` property of `Scaffold` is a `Stack` widget, whose first child(`BackSurface()`) makes up the back surface of backdrop and second child is a `Material` widget with `elevation` of 30.0 to draw shadow along with some `padding` applied to it.

PS: Same color is applied to both `appBar` and `BackSurface()` to make them look continuous but essentially they are different widgets.

```cpp
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(  // Appbar
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text('Some Title'),
        elevation: 0.0,
        actions: [
          ...
        ],
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            BackSurface(), // Widget to store back surface contents
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                top: frontSurfaceTopPadding,
                left: frontSurfaceSidePadding,
                right: frontSurfaceSidePadding,
              ),
              child: Material( // Material which makes up front surface of backdrop
                elevation: 30.0,
                color: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(30.0),
                ),
                clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
                child: IgnorePointer(
                  ignoring: isPanelVisible ? false : true,
                  child: FrontSurfaceWidget(), // Widget to store front surface contents
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up moving the `AppBar` from `Scaffold` to `BackSurface()` widget and it worked. Making `AppBar` as a child of `BackSurface()` widget preseves the shadow of `Material()`.

This is how I modified the `BackSurface()` widget:

```cpp
class BackSurface extends StatelessWidget {
  const BackSurface({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      child: ListView(
        children: [
          Container( // This container has AppBar
            height: 40.0,
            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            child: AppBar(
              centerTitle: true,
              title: Text('widget.appbarTitle'),
              elevation: 0.0,
              actions: [
                if (true)
                  IconButton(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
                    onPressed: () {},
                    icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
                  ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          // other child widgets of back surface
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```